# Angularjs expression not showing up in ngDialog template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-dialog

I'm using ng-repeat to populate user objects from Firebase, in addition to using the ngDialog library. My goal is that when you click on, say a 'view' button, a small dialog would pop-up where you can view a user's details. However, I'm trying to follow the documentation for ngDialog and my popup template isn't rendering any of the expressions.

Data model:

```
{
"members": {
"-JWT5y43YFy1mGirVVS2": {
  "date": 1410328158691,
  "firstname": "Michael",
  "image": "http://telehealth.org/wp-content/images/user-placeholder.jpg",
  "upcoming": "PTO on Thursday",
  "status": {
    "color":  "red",
    "contact": {
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "yahoo": "yahooIM"
    },
    "projects": {
      "projectone": "project one",
      "projecttwo": "project two",
      "projectthree": "project three",
      "projectfour": "project four",
      "projectfive": "project five",
      "projectsix": "project six",
      "projectseven": "project seven",
      "projecteight": "project eight",
      "projectnine": "project nine",
      "projectten": "project ten"
    }
  }
},
"-JWT65QvjwD4TSFjDx4V": {
  "date": 1410328192928,
  "firstname": "Magic",
  "image": "http://telehealth.org/wp-content/images/user-placeholder.jpg",
  "upcoming": "PTO on Thursday",
  "status": {
    "color":  "yellow",
    "contact": {
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "yahoo": "yahooIM"
    },
    "projects": {
      "projectone": "project one",
      "projecttwo": "project two",
      "projectthree": "project three",
      "projectfour": "project four",
      "projectfive": "project five",
      "projectsix": "project six",
      "projectseven": "project seven",
      "projecteight": "project eight",
      "projectnine": "project nine",
      "projectten": "project ten"
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid" ng-repeat="member in members">
  <li class="{{member.status.color}}">
    <div class="dripicon profilephoto">&#xe084;</div>
    <div>
        <h3>{{member.firstname}}</h3>
        <div class="dripicon actions" 
            ng-click="viewStatus()">&#xe077;</div>

        <div class="dripicon actions" 
            ng-click="editStatus()">&#xe036;</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MembersController', function($scope, $firebase, $location, ngDialog){

var ref = new Firebase('https://scrumcheck.firebaseio.com/members');
var members = $firebase(ref);

$scope.members = members.$asObject();

  $scope.viewStatus = function(){
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'views/popupTmpl.html' });
  }

  $scope.editStatus = function(){
    //not entered yet
  }

});
```

popupTmpl.html

```
<p>External modal template with external scope: <code>{{member.firstname}}</code></p>
```

When I click on the 'view' button, triggering the viewStatus() function, I don't get anything for {{member.firstname}} - anyone have any suggestions based off of what you see?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In popupTmpl.html, you have to write ng-repeat = "member in members" then write {{memeber.firstname}}